# How to programmatically set highlight for a Mark Line in Apache Echarts?

Tags: charts, highlight, linechart, echarts, apache-echarts

Is there a way to dispatch an action to show highlight for a Mark Line?

In this example, I can dispatch an action to show a tooltip or show highlight for a data point but can't find a way to do the same for mark line.

- Setup Echarts options

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
    title: {
        text: 'How to highlight a Mark Line?'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    xAxis:  {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['2017-10-14','2017-10-15','2017-10-16','2017-10-17','2017-10-18','2017-10-19','2017-10-20']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            type:'line',
            data:[0.83, 0.32, 0.75, 0.66, 0.77, 0.71, 0.79],
            itemStyle : { normal: {label : {show: true}}},
            markLine: {
                 data: [{name: 'How to highlight a Mark Line?', xAxis: '2017-10-16'}],
            }
        }
    ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

- Dispatch actions

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'showTip',

    // Find  by index or id or name.
    // Can be an array to find multiple components.
    seriesIndex: 0,
    dataIndex: 2
    });
  
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'highlight',

    // Find  by index or id or name.
    // Can be an array to find multiple components.
    seriesIndex: 0,
    dataIndex: 4
    });
}, 200);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngmikeng/28fgvktr/8/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to archive the requirement above that we can use the function `setOption` in the chart instance to update the line style of a mark line.

https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption

Because the mark line is a child attribute of the line series option, so we have to update the whole line series option to make it work. I've also created a variable name `seriesLineOption` to reuse it in the `setOption` function.

- Setup Echarts options

```js
const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
const seriesLineOption = {
  type:'line',
  data:[0.83, 0.32, 0.75, 0.66, 0.77, 0.71, 0.79],
  itemStyle : { normal: {label : {show: true}}},
  markLine: {
    data: [{name: 'How to highlight a Mark Line?', xAxis: '2017-10-16'}],
  }
};

option = {
    title: {
        text: 'How to highlight a Mark Line?'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    xAxis:  {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['2017-10-14','2017-10-15','2017-10-16','2017-10-17','2017-10-18','2017-10-19','2017-10-20']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {...seriesLineOption}
    ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

- Implement the toggle highlight function

```js
const btnHighlight = document.getElementById('btn-highlight');
let highlighted = false;
btnHighlight.addEventListener('click', event => {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: highlighted ? 'hideTip' : 'showTip',

    // Find  by index or id or name.
    // Can be an array to find multiple components.
    seriesIndex: 0,
    dataIndex: 2
    });
  
  const curOption = myChart.getOption();
  const seriesOption = curOption.series[0].markLine.lineStyle = {
    width: 3
  };
  
  myChart.setOption({
     series: [
        {
            ...seriesLineOption,
            markLine: {
              ...seriesLineOption.markLine,
              lineStyle: {
                width: highlighted ? 1 : 3
              }
            }
        }
    ]
  });
  
  highlighted = !highlighted;
});
```

Worked demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngmikeng/s47fjy3k)